# Nested conditional operator in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

Using VS 2013 (not C# 6.0 yet)

I have the following LINQ which works:

```
var radData = (from stop in dbContext.stop_details
               join del in dbContext.stop_event on stop.id equals del.stop_id into Inners
               from sd in Inners.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where stop.ship_date == startDate && stop.cust_ref_5_terminalID == "HEND"
               select new
               {
                   shipDate = stop.ship_date,
                   custRef = stop.cust_ref_5_terminalID,
                   name = stop.customer.customer_name,
                   ontime = (int?)sd.ontime_performance,
                   OTP = ((int?)sd.ontime_performance) < 1 ? "Ontime" : "Late"
               }).ToList();
```

But the value of `OTP` needs to be the following depending on `ontime_performance`:

- Null - "open"
- <1 "Ontime"
- 1 "One Day Late"
- 2 "Two Days Late"
- '>2 "Three or more days late"

Is there a way to nest this?  Nothing I have tried so far works..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain many `?:` as follows:

```
var radData = (from stop in dbContext.stop_details
               join del in dbContext.stop_event on stop.id equals del.stop_id into Inners
               from sd in Inners.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where stop.ship_date == startDate && 
                     stop.cust_ref_5_terminalID == "HEND"

               let value = ((int?)sd.ontime_performance)
               select new
               {
                   shipDate = stop.ship_date,
                   custRef = stop.cust_ref_5_terminalID,
                   name = stop.customer.customer_name,
                   ontime = (int?)sd.ontime_performance,
                   OTP = value == null ? "Open" :
                         value < 1 ? "On time" :
                         value == 1 ? "One Day Late" : 
                         value == 2 ? "Two Days Late" : "Three or more days late"
               }).ToList();
```

Also you can store the field in a variable so you don't need to cast it each time: `let value = ((int?)sd.ontime_performance)`

*BTW - the field being `int?` you can change the `value < 1` to `value == 0`. Consistent with the other conditions and less confusing*

Comment: Perfect --  Thanks for the extra with the value part as well.  The <1 needs to stay as there are negative values returned as well.  Great answer.